# Не могу связать apache с php

Tags: apache, php

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку

> `Not Found`
>
> `The requested URL /php_dir/php-cgi.exe/index.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: ставте как модуль и не морочьте себе голову :)

Comment: а по подробней, какой модуль?

Answer (score 2):

открываешь httpd.conf файл, и где нибудь в самом низу прописываешь:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php5/php5apache.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

к сведению: для Apache 1.3 подключаем php5apache.dll.
Apache 2.0 - php5apache2.dll.
Apache 2.2 - php5apache2_2.dll.

далее
перезапуск сервера и дело в шляпе. php установлен как модуль апача